# Define execution order in custom file filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring 3.1 MVC application in which a user can upload a file and apply some filters over the text. For example, one filter can delete special chars and other can recognize grammar errors.

In my first implementation I used a DB settings table with the name of the filters and a boolean value indicating if the app should execute it or not. The I just have to get the active filter's names and go to a hashtable to get the instances (Objects implementing FileFilter interface) and execute them. This approach was really simple and was working nice until I created new filters.

I have two problems with these new filters:

1. Some filters have dependencies. A user couls select to run ONLY filter C but this filter require filters A and B to be executed as well.
2. Some filters need to be executed in order. Filter A, for example, can be executed in any moment but filter B must to be executed after C and D in that specific order.

My question for you (and my real problem) is, how can I change my implementation to adapt it to these new filters without add a lot of code and in a clean way?

Comment: I would provide to the user only choice between meta-filters (ie. possible filters combinations).

Comment: Meta-filters (filter combinations) is a nice idea. I'll have to consider if I can apply it to my scenario. My main concern is that I could define a meta-filter with filters B, C and D but I still want the user to be able to execute only C or D.

Comment: If C and D have no deps you can add a meta-filter with C only and another with D only

Comment: This seems like a case for the Gang of Four. How about the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not sure if Chain of Responsibility is a good patter to apply here. As I said, a single filter could have serveral dependencies and the execution order could change from one filter to another.

Comment: Exactly, so you build a literal "chain" of filters that do that they need to then delegate to the next filter in the chain. If the user adds, say, `C` then `C` will call `B` which then calls `A`. Etc...